# Can't make dynamic dimension in tensorflow variable

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, initialization, tensor

I have the following code:

```py
a = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float64, shape = (10, None))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((20, 10), dtype = tf.float64), dtype = tf.float64)
c = tf.matmul(b, a)
d = tf.shape(a)[1]
e = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, d), dtype = tf.float64), dtype = tf.float64)
```

I want to set the dimension of `e` during the execution. But I get an error. Isn't it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Tensorflow doesn't allow *dynamic* shape in variable definition, because it can't allocate the memory of arbitrary size during graph definition. So the dimensions of `e` must be known *statically*.

Comment: Does it allow for tf.constant?

Comment: The same. `tf.constant` needs to be known statically